# Опакечивание программы

Tags: tftp, c++, linux

Пишу программу генерации спеков для создания пакетов для RedHat, Gentoo и Debian. Всвязи с этим ищу людей, которым было бы интересно создать пакеты из своих программ. Вам пакеты, мне тестирование. Так же могу положить собранные пакеты в свой репозитарий.

Для этого мне нужны лишь исходники и команды сборки.

Да, кому интересна судьба моего tftp, его можно поставить из http://repo.centerix.ru/. Пакеты: msv-tftp клиент и msv-tftpd сервер.

Comment: отличный способ собрать немного сорцов у людей!

Comment: отличный способ собрать проверенных сорцов лежит в /usr/portage/. А здесь я хочу немного другого.

Comment: посмотрел бы ваш генератор

Comment: @mikelsv, а вот метод просто с tar-файлом c выполнением make, make install Вам не нравится?

Лично я не люблю не глядя ставить в систему чужой софт.

Comment: @avp make install деинсталлировать неудобно

Comment: @sercxjo, генератор можно скачать отсюда: svn://svn.loglist.org/usr/svn/opensource . Логин, пароль: anon. Проект в папке lapa, для работы сборки потребуется папка /msvlib/. Собирать в MSVS или g++. В принципе могу выложить готовый бинарник.

Конвертировать: ./lapa convert ./mhost-1.1.tlapa -f centos . В *.tlapa спецификации для моих программ, которые успешно собираются под три линукса. Форматы: RedHat, Gentoo и Debian.

Еще можно использовать:  ./lapa convertl, которая наоборот сгенерит tlapa из форматов RedHat и ArchLinux.

Остальные функции лучше не трогать, они из старой версии.

Comment: @avp, во первых да, удаление сразу хромает, а во вторых один из аргументов для установки пакетов в том, что при сборке из исходников можно повредить систему.

Comment: @mikelsv, дело Ваше, (make uninstall тоже можно написать). 

Просто tar можно раскрыть, посмотреть, что будет делаться, почитать доку (если есть) и потом решить - ставить, собрать и попробовать "по месту" и т.п.

А с пакетом что делать? Не люблю я этого.

Comment: @avp, пакет тоже можно раскрыть и посмотреть, что там внутри. И установить руками.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он, во-первых, не содержит вопроса, а во-вторых, изложенное в нём предложение, скорее всего, давно не актуально.